# Opening a file at a location where I encounter a hit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, solrnet

I am using ASP.Net MVC with C# and SOLRNET for my search tool. The files I index include .pdf files, word docs, excel etc...
I am able to search and retrieve all the docs with a hit. Now the problem lies in opening the files with a hit.
When I open the file, it should open at the location where the hit is encountered. How do i manage this? It will be even more helpful if I can highlight the hit inside the opened document?

Please help me in solving this.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the file type, or more precisly it depends on the plugin/tool used by browser to render the document

For example, for pdf you can specify on which page to open using following

```
<a href="document.pdf#page=123">
```

Word/Excel is a bit more complicated, I think there is no direct URL support, but you could in theory equip a document with AutoOpen/Exec macro which will auo-search for and highlight hits for user

All in all, there is no universal solution.

Comment: Thanks for the reply..But is there a way to open the pdf at the exact position where the hit occurs. For example, I may not know the page num where the hit is present. In that case how do i traverse the pdf and find the location.